# Navigate to record detail page from visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, navigation

I have a table of related records on a visualforce page and I want to redirect to the respective record detail page when the user clicks on a forward icon associated with each row of the table. navigateToSobject does not work in this case. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick way to have URL way. Just redirect to URL "/" and task will be completed.

If you are determined to use lightning in this case. Have a custom component with pagereference navigation. And on click of button you can trigger the event to lightning component which will invoke the pagereference redirection.

PS - navigateToSobject will still not work in this case from VF page. Because it works only in one.app container or in LEX.